# Buffer overflow attack, possible to regenerate a random canary?

Tags: random, buffer, overflow

I'm working on a system security project with the topic: buffe roverflow attack. 
I do have a program and the sourcecode I should gain root permissions with.
The problem I have is caused by a random canary, at the beginning ot the program the random number generator is initialized:

```
srand(time(NULL) ^ (getpid() << 16));
```

later on the canary gets set by

```
canary = rand();
```

My question: Is it possible to regenerate the canary? I would like to regenerate the salt (time(NULL) returns the time since 1970 in seconds and pid is constant as the program starts) and then get the canary by calling rand().
I'm not familiar with any script language and do not have a lot linux experience, so I hope not to waste time with a solution that would never work. 
Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. All you need to know is the program's start time and process ID. You can get this information from the command line by entering `ps -eo pid,cmd,lstart | grep «program-name»`. For example, suppose the program you're interested in is called `test`:

```
$ ps -eo pid,cmd,lstart | grep test
  26798 ./test                      Thu Oct 26 22:03:52 2017
```

The number at the start of the output line is the process ID, and the time at which this process started is at the end of the line. You can easily convert this to a Unix timestamp:

```
$ date --date='Thu Oct 26 22:03:52 2017' '+%s'
1509055432
```

Last time I checked, PHP was still using the same random number generator. So you can use PHP to calculate the canary:

```
$ php -r 'srand(1509055432 ^ (26798 << 16)); echo rand()."\n";'
1670313680
```

(If you don't have PHP, you could easily roll your own C application to do this calculation for you.)

It should be quite obvious that `srand(time(NULL))` is of no use whatsoever if you want to generate values that are hard to guess. A better approach would be to fetch bytes from `\dev\urandom` instead.

Comment: Are you shure that php and c are using the same rand-generator? If I try it with my own written C application it works, but with PHP it doesnt.

Comment: The implementation of `rand()` seems to be platform-dependent. In Debian I get the same results with C and PHP. In OS X, the C program gives a different result. You should be fine as long as you compile your program with the same library as the target application.